# How to sort or group array elements on base on 2 different id's

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array output from when I print my array:

```
   Array
  (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [categoryID] => 5
        [categoryName] => category 1
        [parentID] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [categoryID] => 6
        [categoryName] => category 2
        [parentID] => 2
    )

 .....


[6] => Array
    (
        [categoryID] => 11
        [categoryName] => Sub Category 11
        [parentID] => 5
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [categoryID] => 12
        [categoryName] => Sub category 12
        [parentID] => 6
    )
```

What I want is to move the category 11 with parentID 5, under the category which has categoryID 5, and the one with parentID 6, under the category with the category 6

That would look like:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [categoryID] => 5
        [categoryName] => category 1
        [parentID] => 2
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [categoryID] => 11
        [categoryName] => Sub category 11
        [parentID] => 5
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [categoryID] => 6
        [categoryName] => category 2
        [parentID] => 2
    )
[7] => Array
    (
        [categoryID] => 12
        [categoryName] => Sub category 12
        [parentID] => 6
    )
```

Comment: You should at least show us what you actually tried then.

Comment: also show output result what you are expecting

Comment: `ksort` is pretty pointless to begin with here - you don’t want to sort _by keys_, so what could that function possibly do for you? The usual approach for “custom” sorting, is `usort` with a self-written comparison function, that for any two passed elements decides, which one is “lower” than the other. (Not sure if that will actually work here though in the usual, trivial way – because your function would not only need to determine, that cat 11 belongs below cat 5, but it would also need to be able to determine the order for any other comparison, cat 11 with cat 6, cat 11 with cat 12, etc.)

Comment: I edited my question, please check again.

Comment: Also, a full, _proper_ example would also not hurt - you got `[parentID] => 2` in there, but no actual category 2 anywhere. So is this _supposed_ to be just a partial data set, or …?

Comment: Array is huge, this is partial data set, just to show what I  am trying to acomplish