# Display results from mysql as navigation tree

Tags: mysql, sorting, parentid

I have the following table:

categoryID
categoryName
parentID

| categoryID | categoryName | parentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Category6 | 0 |
| 7 | Category7 | 0 |
| 12 | Category12 | 6 |
| 13 | Category13 | 7 |

How can I get the following order:

| categoryID | categoryName | parentID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Category6 | 0 |
| 12 | Category12 | 6 |
| 7 | Category7 | 0 |
| 13 | Category13 | 7 |

That is each "child" category to go under it's parent?

I tried with different select and ordering, group by queries, but nothing seems to work.

This question has been marked as duplicate, but it is not. Solution posted on: [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)
does not help me, since it shows record for selected category, and I want the whole tree.

Comment: What about doing it application side?

Comment: I am still trying to re-order the PHP array, without much luck. I hoped SQL will be easier...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67788864/how-to-sort-or-group-array-elements-on-base-on-2-different-ids?noredirect=1#comment119819621_67788864